# Converting list of strings to xml

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

One of my database tables has a lot of records with a column containing xml data stored as a string. What is the best way of retrieve this data and parse the string to get specific information which i wish to bind to my UI. Currently I am doing this -

The data column of my Customer table has the xml data stored as a string

```
List<string> myData = new List<string>();
//populate the list with the data from the customer table
List<XElement> myXmlData = new List<XElement>();
foreach (var item in myData)
 {
      XElement xmlItem = XElement.Parse(item);
      myXmlData.Add(xmlItem);
 }

this.DataContext = myXmlData;
```

I am then using a data template to bind to the xml data that i require using the following

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Element[Name].Value}"/>
```

This works corrcctly but I am not sure if it's the right way of doing things. Performance is a concern so would doing this in any other way improve performance ?

Comment: google XML Data Binding in WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that performance is a *concern* - but have you measured it? Is it a *problem*? This should be your first line of attack.

In terms of the code - I'd use LINQ more thoroughly:

```
List<XElement> myXmlData = myData.Select(XElement.Parse).ToList();
this.DataContext = myXmlData;
```

If the method group conversion doesn't work (the rules are subtle and I can't test it easily right now) you can use a lambda expression:

```
List<XElement> myXmlData = myData.Select(x => XElement.Parse(x)).ToList();
this.DataContext = myXmlData;
```

Note that if your "populate the list" involves LINQ, you may well be able to do the whole thing in one go - e.g.

```
this.DataContext = dbContext.Customers
                            .Select(c => c.CustomerXml)
                            .AsEnumerable() // Out of LINQ to SQL or whatever
                            .Select(XElement.Parse)
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specific information you need from the XML data (it's not clear from your question whether the XML is actually stored as a string or whether that is what your aim is?), have you considered de-serialising it into objects and then extracting the relevant data from there?

XSD is a great .NET tool that can help with this by automatically creating the classes for you. There is some information at http://www.cricketmx.com/articles/read/using-xsd-to-assist-in-xml-deserialisation-to-objects-in-c-sharp/